# Fstream class - issue about' >> ' operator

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, text-files, fstream

a simple program that create array with int numbers from .txt file that looks like

```
2 3
5 7
4 2
y x
y x
...
```

so it's simple nx2 (where n can be unlimited lines). and then fill new file with that array (later I will add code to edit this array with some funny algoritm).

I have written that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ofstream outFile;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("krol.txt");
    int l=0;
    int i=2;
    char ch;
    while (fout.good()){
        if (fout >> ch=='\n') l++;
    }
    fout.close();
    fout.open("krol.txt");
    int temp[l][2];
    int savel=l;
    l=0;
        while (fout >> (temp[l][i])){
        i++;
        if(i==2){ 
         i=0; l++;
        }
    }
    outFile.open("save.txt");
    for (int i=0, j=0;j<savel;i++){
        if (i==2) {
        i=0; j++;
        }
        outFile << temp[j][i];
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
    }
```

but it returns :

```
13 15 C:\Users\Filip\Dysk Google\Infa\krol.cpp [Error] no match for 'operator>>' in 'fout >> ch' 

20 29 C:\Users\Filip\Dysk Google\Infa\krol.cpp [Error] no match for 'operator>>' in 'fout >> temp[l][i]'
```

any ideas?

Comment: It is related to the difference between an output stream and an input stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ofstream` is an *output* file stream; you can't read from it using `>>`.

Instead of `ofstream fout;` I suspect you want `ifstream fin;`.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) is an output stream, so it has no input stream operator>>. If you want to stream into a file, you need `std::ifstream`.